# tweepy, twitter, query parameters are missing, Code25

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am fairly new to python and am having difficulty with the dealing with the twitter API. I have been working with tweepy and working with code similar at several different questions answered on statsexchange before. When I run most of the examples I get good results. However, when I run the code from that involves tweepy.Cursor(api.search,...) I always get the following error:

tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Query parameters are missing.', u'code': 25}]

This error happens when I run this code:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#ps4", count=100,
                       lang="en",
                       since_id=2014-11-25).items():
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
```

Or when I run this:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                   q="#IS",
                   count=100,
                   result_type="recent",
                   include_entities=True,
                   lang="en").items():
print tweet.tweet
```

What would be causing this error when these seemed to work fine in previous questions?

Comment: Both example works fine for me, except in 2nd, `print tweet.text` would be valid statement. and since_id is supposed to be a twitter status id, not date.